# Symfony : migration fail because the command run an unexpected old version

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration, symfony4

From Symfony 4, I am on (migration) version `20190708084642` and the only next version is `20190708121109` (I generated a Migration file named "Version20190708121109.php")

If I execute the command `./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`, I get this SQL error :

[image]

because the `./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` command run a old migration file. Why this command execute an old migration file ? (the `20190701095432`)

Is it normal ?

**EDIT** : in my database, my current migration version is `20190708084642`, I see this same current version also when I execute the command `./bin/console doctrine:migrations:status`

Comment: I will often run `rm -f src/Migrations/Version*` before running `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` and then `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` to prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: delete all Versions files is a bad practice no ? If no..I will simply remove the old migration version file

Comment: but I don't understand why the command play a old migration version file when I just want an update to the next version

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of any of the `Versions...` files? You'll see that older `Versions` will try to do things to your database that are simply no longer valid if the *current* state of your db does not match accordingly. You could always just delete the offending lines from the file if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this will solving your problem, but, in my case, i change my sql from phpMyAdmin to MySql 5.7. and my problem is done